# Can not get number of xml nodes from document using spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, xpath, spring-integration

I am attempting to get the count of the //Root/Record elements using spring integrations int-xml:xpath-header-enricher. It comes back zero regardless of the document passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your XPath expression like this:

```
   <int-xml:xpath-expression id="countExpression" expression="count(//ns:Ephemeris/ns:Record)"
                  ns-prefix="ns"
                  ns-uri="http://www.sandia.gov/pgmm/Ephemeris"/>
```

And have it as a reference from the `<int-xml:header>` instead.

The problem is that your root element in the XML comes with the `xmlns="http://www.sandia.gov/pgmm/Ephemeris"`, so, there is no other way unless we honor namespaces in your source XML. For this purpose we introduce artificial prefix, even if your source XML does have then. We need that in XPath to properly distinguish elements based on some namespace.

I think default `DocumentBuilderFactory` just doesn't honor namespaces making your possible XPath expressions much horrible when it comes to several namespaces support.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add one more whitespace to appear it as a code. Done now!